# Embedding fonts in html kitted R markdown Presentation

Tags: rstudio, markdown, r-markdown, knitr

When I create a html Presentation with slidy (Rmarkdown and Rstudio) and knit it to an html, any latex equation are not displayed properly if I am offline.

How can I change that?

````
---
title: "MinimalExample"
author: "keks"
date: "9 9 2019"
output: slidy_presentation
---

## R Markdown

$\pi = \frac{ a }{ b }$

```{r}
plot(seq(1,19))
```
````

Here is a minimal example, where the $xyz$ Equation is only properly shown, if I am online.

Comment: ah yes, you're right that pandoc's [`--self-contained` option](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options-affecting-specific-writers) doesn't work for mathjax. so either use `--katex` or download the [mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/) files and use `--mathjax myLocalMathjax.js`

Comment: The local mathjax version does not seem to work. I downloaded the zip from https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/archive/2.7.3.zip and put the path in the markdown header.    

`output:`
`html_document:`
`mathjax: "MathJax-2.7.3/MathJax.js"` 
The problem still persists.

Comment: ah yes, seems [this is quite hard to do](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/682), as the MathJax script loads more files at runtime... but why not use `pandoc --katex --self-contained`

Comment: I have two problems with that. The one thing is that I have R code included which does not compile (I change the minimum example accordingly). And the html is now one page, instead of a slide show.